# Jquery.ajax() throw error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Try this link: http://humberinteractive.com/2013/api/index.php?fname=keo

You can see that it take the $_GET['fname'] and print out the content i need.

I tried:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://humberinteractive.com/2013/api/index.php?fname=keo',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work...

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3V8VP/

Help help

Comment: You're returning data in a useless format. You should be returning json or xml.

Comment: [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)?

Comment: I don't think it's the problem, at least it has to return something. I just json_decode it and nothing happened.

Comment: @Samuel I get no response from server?

Answer (score 0):

in your Fiddle, it fails because cross-domain origin ajax request ain't allowed. A common workaround is to use JSONP instead. This won't be a problem if your final app is on the same domain. JSONP code would look like this:

```
<?php

  $data = array("some" => "data"); // make this part yourself
  $callback_name = $_REQUEST["callback"];

  echo $callback_name . "(" . encode_json($data) . ")";

?>
```

Next, the data format is not usable. To pass data from PHP to Javascript, you should use JSON. With php, the function to transform an array/object to a JSON format is [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php).

Lastly, make sure to send correct mime type when you're answering with a JSON object. (PHP function `header()` with correct parameters should do)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3V8VP/1/ Can you take a look and tell me why it give me error?

Comment: Hey, the data you return is well formatted for JSON; although this is not JSONP - google it to get some example (And I edited my answer with JSONP example). Also, note that if you run your javascript code on a page somewhere on `http://humberinteractive.com`, it will work. Cross-Domain origin is only an issue when a page hosted on a site call another site via AJAX (Google it too for more info)

Answer (score 0):

if you do it on different domain, It's may block as the same-origin policy.

then you can try to using JSONP to do so.

by this way, specify `dataType: "jsonp"` for the parameter of the ajax method, then jquery will create a alias of your success method as `xxxxxxxx` and the AJAX request will send with a parameter `callback=xxxxxxxxxx`.

at server side, you need to catch the callback name, and output the same json data as now you have with the callback name like `xxxxxxxxx({....})`

finally your client side will run this this output directly.

for example:

js:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'http://humberinteractive.com/2013/api/index.php?fname=keo',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

server side, for example php:

```
<?php
    // some logic ......
    $json_string = encode_json($data_you_wanna_output);
    echo $_GET['callback'] ."(". $json_string .")";
?>
```

Comment: I have upadted my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({type: "POST", 
         url: 'http://humberinteractive.com/2013/api/index.php', 
        data: {'fname': 'keo'}
    }).done(function( data) {alert(data);});
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to comment and reply you. 
but it's absolutely is some origin policy.

the following message is what appear in Chrome Console.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://humberinteractive.com/2013/api/index.php?fname=keo. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.